# How do I fix "ValueError: could not convert string to float" when running regression from Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I've looked through Stack Overflow and unfortunately the existing answers do not help me.

My code looks as follows:

```
def regress(data1, data2, data3, data4):
    df = insert_worldbankdata(data1, data2, data3, data4) 
    X = df['Women in Parliament (%)'], df['Inflation (%)'], df['Individuals using Internet (%)']
    y = df['Annual Mean Sat.']
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(X, y)
    model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
    predictions = model.predict(X) 
    print_model = model.summary()
    return print_model
```

It returns this error:  **ValueError: could not convert string to float:**

Examples I have tried are:

```
map(float, x)
```

```
df['VARIABLE'] = df['VARIABLE'].astype(float)
```

As well as the replace function.

I'd really appreciate any help. I've been struggling to figure this out for the past few days and been browsing through the Stack Overflow archives.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the values of your columns they should be in the following format '10.5674'

So you have to remove all other characters to avoid this error. Also, you have to remove all the 'nan' 'empty' ... strings. They will cause the same error.

Comment: Thank you, this helped! Now I'm fixing the following issue: `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 1466]`

Comment: You may have deleted rows in your x and keeping them in your y. you must have the same shape in x and y (X.shape[0] != Y.shape[0] )

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding. When I evaluate it I see that all of them have the same length: 1466.

Then when I try and reshape it says "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape' "